# Real-time DOM display of multiple javascript subroutines

Tags: javascript, dom

I have an HTML table which I must fill with some javascript function calculations. The javascript function has some subroutines that each make some calculations and fill the HTML table with the results. The problem is that even if the subroutines spend some time to make the calculations and results are expected to appear successive in time, in fact the results are displayed at once. I really want the results to be displayed as they are calculated, at a few seconds pace.

Comment: Could you put up a JSBin/JSFiddle example of this?

Comment: From your sparse description, it sounds like maybe your "subroutines" are synchronous and blocking the UI update.

Comment: Also, please include a relevant snippet of your code in the question itself.

Comment: Subroutines. Made me think of Star Trek... 
The problem sounds like your computer is too fast?

Answer (score 1):

add a delay using setTimeout function before calling next subroutine calculation, else the browser will update the DOM **only  after** all javascript code has been executed

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your updates are asynchronous they may be fast and appear to happen at the same time.

You could chain the calculations, so the next starts only after each before it ends.